# Word 2007 shows the 2nd page when the file is double clicked

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I've got a weird problem: When I open a word 2007 file by double-clicks, it always show the 2nd page when the file is opened. (instead of the first page or the last modified page)

Have anyone a clue to solve this?

System configuration:
The office 2007 is installed on a windows 7 machine in my office. I have no clue how it is installed.

Comment: Is it doing this for only one specific document/file, or all Word files?

Comment: What happens if its a one page document?

Comment: It happens on all word files.